# Multi line Headers in react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I would like to display more than one row in my headers.

[image]

Previously I was [able to change the header height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113610/alter-column-header-height/44113836#44113836).

Now I want to display multi line text, preferably passed in as an array.

The closest I have come to is digging through some forums and coming across a **HeaderRenderer**, which can be added to my columns like so :

```
    this._columns.push({ 
      key: 'key_empty_' + i,
      name: "asdfasdfasdf ",
      headerRenderer: HeaderRenderer,

    })
```

As far as I can see the HeaderRenderer just takes in a column and this column can then be manipulated.

In order to solve my problem one of these solutions should suffice :

- have the ability to add a component into the Header object
- Have an option to add multi line text into the header
- Allow the code to interpret line breaks. ie. If I currently add "asdfasdf`<br>`asdfasdf" then it just displays as is.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own fix for this. I forked the react-data-grid project and updated the column renderer :

https://github.com/oliverwatkins/react-data-grid